# Burn DVD From .iso

Tags: dvd, dvd-backup

So I own a few commercial DVDs that now don't play very well due to repeated mishandling over the years. But fortunately before then I took backups of them (as .iso images) onto my hard disk.

The .iso file was generated using the dd command.

I've now trying to write them back onto disc using dual layer DVD+R DL discs. I've now written two discs using Brasero (the Burn Image option) and both of them give me a very corrupt video - see an example screenshot below.

I have libdvdcss installed and I'm able to play the video perfectly if I point vlc at the .iso file. But the disc isn't written correctly.

I'm not really very knowledgable about how video formats work on these discs - can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For DVD I use handbrake, for blueray [makemkv](https://www.makemkv.com/) is your friend. A personal copy is legal in my country,so I my "hardware" can be copied to my local server. Since Brasero won't be able to extract any decoding keys (your DVD is encrypted) try [handbrake](https://www.tweaking4all.com/video/rip-dvd-blu-ray/linux-handbrake-copy-a-dvd-to-mp4-or-mkv-file/) to make a personal copy.

Answer (score 0):

I started down the handbrake path, but found that that involved having to set loads of configuration options relating to how the audio and video is to be re-encoded.

Instead of doing this I managed to find out that a DVD video disc is simply a disc that contains a /VIDEO_TS/ directory with some files that follow a particular naming convention. And that there's a utility called vobcopy, which makes copies of all of the files in this directory without the CSS copy protection. Using this I can then create another .iso image with the identical files from the original DVD, minus the copy protection so that they play properly on the DVD player.